# Powershell: dynamic variables within foreach

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I am trying to do some math for a dynamic list of users that I will use to run a search and count some results anonymously, then add to a running total per user.  So, for instance:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -filter blah
[int]$usercount = $users.count

for ($z=1; $z -le $usercount; $z++) {
    **** create variable here - $user$z ***
}
```

When the variable is created, I need it available for further loops where I will add a count to the number already stored in the variable.

And no, I can't use the $user variable, because it must persist after this foreach loop ends.

So, the question is, how to I generate that incrementing variable not knowing the limit of the count of possible objects?

**---EDIT---**

Adding an easy example of what I am talking about...

After feedback, I am looking at hashtables, but still can't figure out how to reference.

Imagine a dice game between a dynamic list of people with multiple rounds.  I want to increment per round their total.  My problem is the last line where I try to update the total with the roll.  How do I reference the hashtable value?

```
[CmdletBinding()]

param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][ValidateRange(1, [int32]::MaxValue)][int]$rounds = "15",
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][ValidateRange(1, [int32]::MaxValue)][int]$players = "2"
)

$ptotal = [ordered]@{}
for ($w=1; $w -le $players; $w++) {
    $ptotal.add("player$w", 0)
}

for ($z=1; $z -le $rounds; $z++) {
    Write-Host Round $z

    for ($y=1; $y -le $players; $y++) {

        $roll = (1..6 | get-random) + (1..6 | get-random)
        $ptotal.player$y = $ptotal.player$y + $roll
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to declare the var beforehand in PS. But you should also research variable scope, which is going to cause problems with the way you're going right now.

Comment: I actually do need to declare beforehand, because I will have multiple loops later that will add, so I cannot just use a variable within the loop.  Also understand the scope concern, and I will deal with that, I am just looking for how to create the variable in a way that I can read it later...

Comment: So long as you continue to reference the vars using $Script:var_name you can manipulate them throughout the script, in any loop or function. If this is not what you are asking, perhaps you can clarify?

Comment: You can create variables with `New-Variable` cmdlet. As `for` loop does not introduce new scope, them will be available in following loops in current scope by default. You can specify desired scope as parameter to `New-Variable` cmdlet as well. But, unless you can provide good justification for using variables with dynamic names, you should consider using array instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your example it would be `$ptotal["player$y"] += $roll`

You can use Hashtables both like associative arrays and objects.  Very good reading about them is https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2016-11-06-powershell-hashtable-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about/ (on top of official documentation, of course)

Comment: @Steven you are welcome. You can use "Vote up" as an expression of gratitude ;)

Comment: @maoizm "Vote up" require 15 points, but OP only have 3.